# When to prefer using vkCmdPipelineBarrier inside a renderpass rather than subpass dependency?

Tags: vulkan, memory-barriers

Say we have two subpass where the render target of the first one became an input for the fragment shader in the second one.

We can use a pipeline barrier to ensure second subpass fragment shader won't begin reading image unless the previous subpass already finished writing into it.

```
const VkImageMemoryBarrier imageMemoryBarriers =
{
    VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER,     
    nullptr,                                    
    VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,       // srcAccessMask
    VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT,                  // dstAccessMask
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL,   // oldLayout
    VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL,   // newLayout
    VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED,                    
    VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED,                    
    image,                                      
    {                                           // subresourceRange
        VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT,              // aspectMask
        0,                                      // baseMipLevel
        VK_REMAINING_MIP_LEVELS,                // levelCount
        0,                                      // baseArrayLayer
        VK_REMAINING_ARRAY_LAYERS               // layerCount
    }
};

vkCmdPipelineBarrier(m_currentCommandBuffer,
                     VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,
                     VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT,
                     0,
                     0, nullptr,
                     0, nullptr,
                     1, &imageMemoryBarrier);
```

But we can use instead a subpass dependency for achieving the same synchronization as follows:

```
const VkSubpassDependency dependencies =
{
        0,                                              // srcSubpass
        1,                                              // dstSubpass
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT,  // srcStageMask
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT,          // dstStageMask
        VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,           // srcAccessMask
        VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT,                      // dstAccessMask
        VK_DEPENDENCY_BY_REGION_BIT                     // dependencyFlags
}
```

I have two questions about this:

(1) I read that using subpass dependency is preferred , why?   it seems that using memory barrier shrink the constrains only for a specific image, while subpass dependency applies the synchronization over execution.  It means that when using memory barrier , the GPU avoid waiting for other images involved, and wait only for specific image set in the barrier, while in subpass dependency, execution of stage is waiting, for whole images.

(2) When should we prefer to use memory/execution barrier in a subpass rather than subpass dependency?

Comment: You mean `VK_ACCESS_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT` in the examples?

Comment: The question is kinda moot though, because in subpass self-dependency (`vkCmdPipelineBarrier` inside a subpass) you are not allowed to change layout as you do in your example.

Comment: @krOoze - regarding your comment about VK_ACCESS_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT value - I followed the code shown in the book "Vulkan Programming Guide" by  John Kessenich, chapter 13 - Multipass Rendering. The dependencies.dstAccessMask value is VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT. Is it wrong?

Comment: @krOoze - regarding your second comment -  if I understand well, such pipeline barrier as I shown may be used between renderpasses, but there is no such thing - pipeline barrier between subpasses. I need to re-arrange my thoughts and understanding, then will edit this question. Thanks.

Comment: Alright, that complicates matters even more. `VK_ACCESS_SHADER_READ_BIT` implies non-attachment use. And I think attachment + non-attachment use in render pass is largely forbidden.

Comment: "Pipeline barrier between subpasses" is made by `VkSubpassDependency`. If you use actual `vkCmdPipelineBarrier` inside subpass, it has a different meaning than usual barrier. It is a _subpass self-dependency_. It is a dependency that is limited to only that single subpass, and nothing else. (And it is not allowed to have layout change, because that is handled by the renderpass and it would clash).

Comment: Theoretically you could use `LAYER_GENERAL`, but access of image as attachment and non-attachment is largely forbidden too.

Comment: @krOoze  -Thanks for all answers, it gives clues and directions to search and tune my understanding.